# Problem with \IfStrEqCase combined with \StrChar

Tags: xstring

Upon compiling this minimal example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\digit}[1]{
    \IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
        {0}{zero}%
        {1}{one}%
        {2}{two}%
    }[many]%
}

\begin{document}
\digit{1}
\digit{2}
\digit{3}
\digit{\StrChar{456}{2}}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\@testopt #1#2->\kernel@ifnextchar [{#1
                                       }{#1[{#2}]}
```

Is it possible to make this code work?

Comment: No, it's not possible like this: `\StrChar{456}{2}` is not a digit, but a set of (unexpandable) instruction to possibly produce one.

Comment: @egreg Are there some fundamental obstacles from making it expandable?

Comment: It would be quite cumbersome with `xstring`; I suggest a method with `expl3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\StrChar{456}{2}` is not a digit, but a set of instructions that (possibly) produces a digit. Instead, `\IfEqStrCase` needs an explicit digit, after full expansion, which is not possible from `\StrChar`.

You can do it with `expl3` (called via `xparse`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\digit}{m}
 {
  \str_case:fnF { #1 }
   {
    {0}{zero}%
    {1}{one}%
    {2}{two}%
   }
   {many}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF { f }

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\extract}{mm}
 {
  \tl_item:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\digit{1}
\digit{2}
\digit{3}
\digit{\extract{456}{2}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I knew you would come with `expl3` :-P