# xstring TeX capacity exceeded

Tags: macros, formatting, xstring, variable

I try to store the result of an `xstring` pagckage’s command in another command (or variable, I don’t care), to reuse it in another `xstring`’s command, as you can see in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

%extract the first letter of the string “Abbbbbbb” and store it on the command “\temp”
\newcommand\temp{\StrChar{Abbbbbbb}{1}}

% Printing the contente of the command “\temp”, normaly it should be “A”
\temp

% Test if the content of the command “\temp” is “A”
\IfStrEq{\temp}{A}{True}{False}
\end{document}
```

When I compile it, I get the following message

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000].
\@xs@IfStrEq@@ #1#2->
                     \@xs@assign \@xs@arg@i {#1}\@xs@assign \@xs@arg@ii {#2}...
l.9 \IfStrEq{\temp}{A}
                      {True}{False}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

I also try to store the `\StrChar` output in a variable instead of command, unfortunately I have the same behavior at the compilation as you can see in this second MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

%extract the first letter of the string “Abbbbbbb” and store it on the variable “\temp”
\def\temp{\StrChar{Abbbbbbb}{1}} % ← It’s only this line who is different from the first MWE

% Printing the contente of the command “\temp”, normaly it should be “A”
\temp

% Test if the content of the command “\temp” is “A”
\IfStrEq{\temp}{A}{True}{False}
\end{document}
```

And I have the same compilation error output.

I think that `\StrChar` produce in his output some formating not-visible commands which disturb `\IfStrEq`. And It would be probably needed to erase this formating not-visible commands before the `\IfStrEq` proceeding. But it’s just an hypothesis.

So how can I store an `\StrChar` output by a way witch can allow me to use this output as in imput of another `xstring`’s command?

Comment: Did you see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274479/problem-with-ifstreqcase-combined-with-strchar

Comment: Don't know what your actual use case is, but if extracting the 1st token of a string is it, it is much simpler without packages: `\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\getfirst[1]{\getfirstaux#1\relax}
\def\getfirstaux#1#2\relax{#1}
\begin{document}
\def\temp{\getfirst{Abbbbbbb}}
\temp\par
\if A\temp True\else False\fi
\end{document}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, I don’t know if your solution is enough because here I give an example with the first character extraction. But I also need to extract the 2d, 3d… nth ones.

Comment: Yes @albert but the given solution by egreg only work for digits so it doesn’t work in my case.

Comment: Is `n` a fixed number known in advance, or is `n` the totality of the string?  Also, there is the `stringstrings` package which can do this, though (as the author) I can say the package has other issues making it less than ideal.

Comment: I have edited my answer to handle arbitrary index of the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I get it: to register the output of an `xstring` command into a variable, it’s wrong to do :

```
\def\temp{\StrChar{Abbbbbbb}{1}}
```

Instead of this, we should add the name of the variable betwean bracket after the `xstring`’s command, like this:

```
\StrChar{Abbbbbbb}{1}[\temp]
```

Then, we could use `\temp` as we want.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a packageless approach.  Note though that spaces in the input are ignored:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\newcounter{getcount}
\newcommand\getn[2]{\setcounter{getcount}{#2}\getnext#1\relax} 
\def\getnext#1#2\relax{%
  \addtocounter{getcount}{-1}%
  \ifnum\thegetcount=0\relax
    \def\thegotten{#1}%
    \def\next{}%
  \else%
    \def\next{\getnext#2\relax\relax}%
  \fi%
  \next%
} 
\begin{document} 
\getn{Abbbbbbb}{1}
\thegotten

\if A\thegotten True\else False\fi 


\getn{Abbebbbb}{4}
\thegotten

\if e\thegotten True\else False\fi 
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

An approach with `stringstrings`.  Notice that spaces are retained in the index count.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\begin{document}
\substring[q]{Abbbbbbb}{1}{1}
\thestring

\if A\thestring True\else False\fi

\substring[q]{Abcde fg}{7}{7}
\thestring

\if A\thestring True\else False\fi
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You discovered that `\newcommand{\temp}{\StrChar{Abbbbbbb}{1}}` *doesn't extract the first item from the given string: remember that TeX never interprets in any way the replacement text given for a `\def` (or `\newcommand` that's a wrapper around it).

Thus your next `\IfStrEq{\temp}{A}{True}{False}` doesn't find an `A`, but rather the whole set of instructions to extract an `A` from `Abbbbbbb`. This is further complicated by the fact that `xstring` macros perform full expansion on their arguments (unless countermanded by `\noexpandarg` or similar declaration, see the manual for more information).

The right way to proceed is to do

```
\StrChar{Abbbbbbb}{1}[\temp]
```

(with the risk of silently overwriting the macro given last, be careful with the names.

You can avoid this by using `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\tldefine}{mm}
 {
  \tl_clear_new:N #1
  \tl_set:Nf #1 { #2 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\tlitem}{smm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   { \tl_item:Nn #2 { #3 } }
   { \tl_item:nn { #2 } { #3 } }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\tlifeq}{mmmm}
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\tldefine\temp{\tlitem{Abbbbbbb}{1}}

\temp

\tlifeq{\temp}{A}{True}{False}

\end{document}
```

Use `\tlitem*` if the first argument is a command which you want to expand.

This prints

> A
>   True

The second argument to `\tlitem` can be a negative number, which means counting from the end.